# TableViewer, defining an initial sorting order has no effect on data

Tags: eclipse, jface, tableviewer

pratically I build up a tableviewer as usual, but initially it does not sort all the rows according the column defined for sorting.

The code I am using:

```
viewer.getTable().setSortColumn(viewer.getTable().getColumn(4));
viewer.getTable().setSortDirection(SWT.UP);
```

Only after clicking manually the column #4 I obtain the correct order, otherwise it follows exactly the "insert order" of the object list linked to the ViewContentProvider. Please can you help me? Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You just need to refresh the table.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem.

When using ...
`tableViewer.setComparator(comparator)`
... the above code is ignored.

You have to set manually the initial sort column index in the extended ViewerComparator.

Answer (score 1):

Building off Devalex's answer, the following worked for me:

```
viewer.setContentProvider(...);
viewer.setInput(...);
viewer.setComparator(myComparator);
myComparator.setColumn(colIndex);
viewer.refresh();
```